# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl, tls, cloudflare

I have seen a few of these questions around but they are related to IIS or something similar.

I am using Apache with Nginx reverse proxy and cloudflare enabled with full (strict) SSL and the PEM and KEY files installed on the server my end.

However when I check out my domain health report I get this error for the webserver: `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

Does anyone know what causes this, how I can troubleshoot it and where the problem is? Is it with cloudflare?

Comment: What is a "domain health report"? Where do you view this? Can we view it? Is the setup working? What problem are you actually having?

Comment: mxtoolbox.com/domain/depressionforteens.com/

Comment: Emails being marked as spam. @tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the domain health report is simply telling you that it can't create an https connection to your website. I don't know why it can't create an https connection, because https works fine for me, and the various SSL checking and general testing sites say it's fine (example [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=DEPRESSIONFORTEENS.COM), [here](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160718_FV_eb26b3a5f781a5ecd1308a409967d4d4/), and [here](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.depressionforteens.com/SA8UfT4c)). I would guess that either mxtoolbox has a problem, or perhaps it's testing secure email. It could be as simple as mxtoolbox doesn't understand the 301 redirect being sent by your website from the root domain to the www subdomain.

I don't think this error is related to spam. You have an SPF record, which is good, but you could also look into DKIM.

I think your question is asking about a red herring.